# A small problem on the derivation of the integral of variable limit

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

Find the derivative of $F(t)$ with respect to $x$.

$$
F(t) =
(t-a)
\int_a^t f(x) g(x) \,\mathrm d x
-
\int_a^t f(x)      \,\mathrm d x
\int_a^t      g(x) \,\mathrm d x
$$

The code attached below is for Wolfram Language input:

```
D[
  (t-a)
  Integrate[ f[x] g[x], {x,a,t} ]
  -
  Integrate[ f[x]     , {x,a,t} ]
  Integrate[      g[x], {x,a,t} ],
  x
]
```

This comes from a step in an example in a book (proving an integral inequality). The book directly gives that the derivative of $F(t)$ is [see below], and what I calculated is inconsistent with it.

$$
F'(t) = \int_a^t \bigl( f(x)-f(t) \bigr) \bigl( g(x)-g(t) \bigr) \,\mathrm d x
$$

Then I tried to expand the expression of integrand in its result to piece together to get the same form, but in the end I figured out:

$$
F'(t) =
\int_a^t \bigl( f(x)-f(t) \bigr)
         \bigl( g(x)-g(t) \bigr)
         \color{Blue}{
         -
         \bigl( f(x)-f(a) \bigr)
         \bigl( g(x)-g(a) \bigr)
         }
         \,
         \mathrm d x
$$

(The blue part is where my calculation result is inconsistent with the book)

Thanks in advance!

---

Here is my wrong calculation process:

$$
\begin{align*}
F'(t)
&=
\left( (t-a) \int_a^t f(x)g(x)\,\mathrm d x \right)'
-
\left( \int_a^t f(x)\,\mathrm d x \int_a^t g(x)\,\mathrm d x \right)'
\\
&=
(t-a) \left( \int_a^t f(x)g(x)\,\mathrm d x \right)'
-
\left(
  \left( \int_a^t f(x)\,\mathrm d x \right)' \int_a^t g(x)\,\mathrm d x
  +
  \int_a^t f(x)\,\mathrm d x \left( \int_a^t g(x)\,\mathrm d x \right)'
\right)
\\
&=
(t-a) \int_a^t \Bigl( f(x)g(x) \Bigr)'\,\mathrm d x
-
\left(
  \int_a^t \Bigl( f(x) \Bigr)' \,\mathrm d x \int_a^t g(x)\,\mathrm d x
  +
  \int_a^t f(x)\,\mathrm d x \int_a^t \Bigl( g(x) \Bigr)' \,\mathrm d x
\right)
\\
&=
(t-a) \left. \Bigl( f(x)g(x) \Bigr) \right\rvert_a^t
-
\left(
  \left. f(x) \right\rvert_a^t \int_a^t g(x)\,\mathrm d x
  +
  \left. g(x) \right\rvert_a^t  \int_a^t f(x)\,\mathrm d x
\right)
\\
&=
\int_a^t \bigl( f(t)g(t) - f(a)g(a) \bigr)\,\mathrm d x
-
\left(
  \int_a^t \bigl(f(t)-f(a)\bigr) g(x)\,\mathrm d x
  +
  \int_a^t \bigl(g(t)-g(a)\bigr) f(x)\,\mathrm d x
\right)
\\
&=
\int_a^t
  \Bigl(
    \bigl( f(t)g(t)-f(a)g(a) \bigr)
    -
    \bigl( f(t)-f(a) \bigr) g(x)
    -
    \bigl( g(t)-g(a) \bigr) f(x)
  \Bigr)
\,\mathrm d x
\\
&=
\int_a^t
  \Bigl(
    f(t)g(t)-f(a)g(a)
   -f(t)g(x)+f(a)g(x)
   -f(x)g(t)+f(x)g(a)
   +f(x)g(x)-f(x)g(x)
  \Bigr)
\,\mathrm d x
\\
&=
\int_a^t
  \Bigl(
    \bigl(f(x)-f(a)\bigr)g(a)
   +\bigl(f(x)-f(t)\bigr)g(x)
   +\bigl(-f(x)+f(t)\bigr)g(t)
   +\bigl(-f(x)+f(a)\bigr)g(x)
  \Bigr)
\,\mathrm d x
\\
&=
\int_a^t
  \Bigl(
    \bigl(f(x)-f(a)\bigr)g(a)
   +\bigl(f(x)-f(t)\bigr)g(x)
   -\bigl(f(x)-f(t)\bigr)g(t)
   -\bigl(f(x)-f(a)\bigr)g(x)
  \Bigr)
\,\mathrm d x
\\
&=
\int_a^t
  \Bigl(
   +\bigl(f(x)-f(t)\bigr)g(x)
   -\bigl(f(x)-f(t)\bigr)g(t)
   +\bigl(f(x)-f(a)\bigr)g(a)
   -\bigl(f(x)-f(a)\bigr)g(x)
  \Bigr)
\,\mathrm d x
\\
&=
\int_a^t
  \biggl(
    \Bigl(
      \bigl(f(x)-f(t)\bigr)
      \bigl(g(x)-g(t)\bigr)
    \Bigr)
    -
    \Bigl(
      \bigl(f(x)-f(a)\bigr)
      \bigl(g(x)-g(a)\bigr)
    \Bigr)
  \biggr)
\,\mathrm d x
\text{.}
\end{align*}
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Mathematica code produces (and this is also correct, by application of the product rule and the [Fundamental Theorem of Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#First_part), if we assume $f$ and $g$ are uniformly continuous on $[a,t]$) \begin{align*}
F'(t) &= \int_a^t f(x) g(x) \,\mathrm{d}x - g(t) \int_a^t f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x - f(t) \int_a^t g(x) \,\mathrm{d}x + (t-a)f(t)g(t)  \\
&= \int_a^t f(x) g(x) \,\mathrm{d}x - \int_a^t f(x) g(t) \, \mathrm{d}x - \int_a^t f(t) g(x) \,\mathrm{d}x + \int_a^t f(t)g(t) \,\mathrm{d}x  \\
&= \int_a^t f(x) g(x) - f(x) g(t) - f(t) g(x) + f(t)g(t) \,\mathrm{d}x  \\
&= \int_a^t f(x) \left( g(x) - g(t)\right) - f(t) \left( g(x) - g(t) \right) \,\mathrm{d}x  \\
&= \int_a^t (f(x) - f(t)) \left( g(x) - g(t)\right) \,\mathrm{d}x  \text{.}
\end{align*}

Your version is *not* equivalent to this, so there must be an error in your work.  You don't show your work, so there is no way to guess what error was made.

Comment: Ashamed, after carefully observing the first step for a long time, I still don’t know how it was produced, so I just attached my wrong process. Please correct me, thank you!

Comment: @mamath : \begin{align*} \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} (t-a) \int_a^t f(x)g(x) \,\mathrm{d}x &= \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\left( (t-a) \right) \int_a^t f(x)g(x) \,\mathrm{d}x + (t-a) \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \int_a^t f(x)g(x) \,\mathrm{d}x  \\  &=  \int_a^t f(x)g(x) \,\mathrm{d}x + (t-a) f(t)g(t) \end{align*} by the product rule and the fundamental theorem of calculus (as cited in the Answer).

Comment: Ah, it turns out that "the **first** fundamental theorem" should be used. I understand this now, but shouldn't the derivation be for the variable $x$?

Comment: @mamath : There almost no consistency in numbering the parts of the Fundamental Theorem (and some move parts into corollaries).
The variable $x$ doesn't exist outside the integrands.  There is no global variable $x$ with respect to which one can differentiate.  Further, $F$ is explicitly written as a function of $t$, so it's unnamed derivatives (indicated by primes) are with respect to that variable.

Comment: In fact, I guessed it a bit. You {filled up, corrected} one of my knowledge {loopholes, misunderstandings} (i.e. reviewed the *first* theorem), thank you so much!